# Go - net/http - extract REST API url without path parameters or query string

Tags: go

I am writing one custom roundtripper where I want to capture client metrics i.e. round trip latency. I'll use this custom roundtripper with http client transport for different REST services. I want to group latency metric as per API method so I am looking for ways to extract REST API path without path parameters or query string. I tried to use r.URL.Path and it gives path without query string but its not truncating path parameters

e.g If there is API like
/data-service/api/v1/streams/2664?start=1645920000000&end=1648512000000

I need extracted path as -> "/data-service/api/v1/streams"

e.g If there is API like
/entities-service/api/v1/entities/1234

I need extracted path as -> "/entities-service/api/v1/entities"

Other cases without path param and query param should be as it is
"session-service/api/v1/token"

r.URL.Path gives "/data-service/api/v1/streams/2664" for first case and "/entities-service/api/v1/entities/1234" for 2nd case(removes query string only). How to strip path params and query params both?

```
type customTransport struct {
    rtp       http.RoundTripper
    reqStart  time.Time
    reqEnd    time.Time
}

func (tr *customTransport) RoundTrip(r *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    tr.reqStart = time.Now()
    resp, err := tr.rtp.RoundTrip(r)
    tr.reqEnd = time.Now()
    // Calculate latency and publish it to prometheus
    latency := tr.reqEnd.Sub(tr.reqStart)
    // Strip path param and query param here
    extractedPath := r.URL.Path
    return resp, err
}
```

Comment: i'm sure that first case's `r.URL.Path` should be `/data-service/api/v1/streams/2664`

Comment: You are right. I missed it. Updated question

Comment: is there any problem if delete the latest number using `path.Dir` or others?

Comment: There is nothing to delete for cases when there is no path or query params

Answer (score 0):

```
    extractedPath := r.URL.Path
    // Strip path param and query param here
    //There is nothing to delete for cases when there is no path or query params
    if r.URL.Path != "" && r.URL.RawQuery != "" {
        extractedPath = path.Dir(r.URL.Path)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", extractedPath)
```

Comment: It's returning incorrect result when path param and query param is not present, e.g. for this case "/session-service/api/v1/token" -> "/session-service/api/v1".